# Better number display for dygraphs

Tags: dygraphs

How can I display numbers via a separator, such as: 1000000 becomes 1,000,000 and such? Interested in something that will work for both the axis and the legend.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your best bet is to use the per-axis option axisLabelFormatter, and valueFormatter.
See per-axis options [here](http://dygraphs.com/per-axis.html)

You could use the function provided by Kanji [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5731193/how-to-format-numbers-using-javascript) to do what you want.