# Javascript multiplication and format

Tags: javascript

been banging my head against the wall all day with this. Could anyone provide some advice please?

I'm trying to multiply (rate * pps) * ts, and return the result in a money format. I've almost got it working, but it's not quite right.

When I enter 5.25 as the percentage for rate, 35.00 for pps, and 1200 for ts, the result is 220500; which is the same as when calculated with a calculator, but I need to return it in the format of £2,205.00

The code I have so far is:

The HTML:

```
<div class="row"><input type="text" name="rate" id="rate" placeholder="Dividend rate (%)  e.g. 5.25" /></div>

<div class="row"><input type="text" name="pps" id="pps" placeholder="Par value (£)  e.g. 1" /></div>

<div class="row"><input type="text" name="totalshares" id="totalshares" placeholder="Total number of shares  e.g. 1000" /></div>

<div class="row"><input type="text" name="marketprice" id="marketprice" placeholder="Market price (£)  e.g. 20" /></div>

<div class="row"><input type="button" value="Calculate dividend" onClick="calculateDividend()" /></div>

<div class="row" id="dividendcont" style="display:none"><input type="text" name="dividend" id="dividend" placeholder="Dividend" /></div>
```

The javascript:

```
function calculateDividend(){
var rate = document.getElementById('rate').value;
var pps = document.getElementById('pps').value;
var ts = document.getElementById('totalshares').value;
var dividend = (rate * pps) * ts;


document.getElementById('dividendcont').style.display="block";
document.getElementById('dividend').value = dividend;
}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

UPDATE:
Thanks Matt. That put me on the right track.
Here's how I done it in the end:

The JS:

```
function calculateDividend(){
var rate = document.getElementById('rate').value;
var pps = document.getElementById('pps').value;
var ts = document.getElementById('totalshares').value;
var mp = document.getElementById('marketprice').value;

var dividend = (rate * pps) * ts;
var total = number_format(dividend / 100, 2, ".", ",");


document.getElementById('dividendcont').style.display="block";
document.getElementById('dividend').value = "£"+total;
}



function number_format (number, decimals, dec_point, thousands_sep) {
// Strip all characters but numerical ones.
number = (number + '').replace(/[^0-9+\-Ee.]/g, '');
var n = !isFinite(+number) ? 0 : +number,
prec = !isFinite(+decimals) ? 0 : Math.abs(decimals),
sep = (typeof thousands_sep === 'undefined') ? ',' : thousands_sep,
dec = (typeof dec_point === 'undefined') ? '.' : dec_point,
s = '',
toFixedFix = function (n, prec) {
  var k = Math.pow(10, prec);
  return '' + Math.round(n * k) / k;
};
// Fix for IE parseFloat(0.55).toFixed(0) = 0;
s = (prec ? toFixedFix(n, prec) : '' + Math.round(n)).split('.');
if (s[0].length > 3) {
s[0] = s[0].replace(/\B(?=(?:\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, sep);
}
if ((s[1] || '').length < prec) {
s[1] = s[1] || '';
s[1] += new Array(prec - s[1].length + 1).join('0');
}
return s.join(dec);
}
```

Thanks for your help everyone

Comment: You will have to do the formatting yourself, or you can use a [library](http://openexchangerates.github.io/accounting.js/). See [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/149055/how-can-i-format-numbers-as-money-in-javascript).

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to format numbers using javascript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5731193/how-to-format-numbers-using-javascript)

Comment: Check this post out,
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2901102/how-to-print-a-number-with-commas-as-thousands-separators-in-javascript
will probably give you some ideas

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You simply need to divide by 100 to turn the cents you get into dollars, then add commas and the pound sign.

Here is an in-depth answer which covers how to format the number as money: [How can I format numbers as money in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/149055/how-can-i-format-numbers-as-money-in-javascript)

Comment: What are cents and dollars?

Comment: Sorry, is it "pennies" and "pounds"?

Comment: @MattWetmore: Yes, it is pounds and pennies. I don't see why to don't use them. I have not problem with them.

Answer (score 0):

The 'most modern' answer is:

```
(value/100).toLocaleString("en-gb",{style:'currency',currency:'GBP',minimumFractionDigits:2})
```

However, this will fail in a variety of older browsers (see [the documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toLocaleString#Browser_compatibility)).

Answer (score 0):

Was interested to see what a function to implement currency formatting in browsers that don't support (or units not supported by) `number.toLocaleString` would look like, came up with this, default currency is GBP

```
function currency(val, unit, tsep, usep, rounder) {
    var re = /(\d+)(?=(?:\d{3})+)/g,
        arr = [];

    if (typeof val !== 'number' || val !== val || val === Infinity || val === -Infinity)
        throw TypeError('Invalid value: ' + val);

    if (typeof unit !== 'string') unit = '£';
    if (typeof tsep !== 'string') tsep = ',';
    if (typeof usep !== 'string') usep = '.';
    if (typeof rounder !== 'function') rounder = Math.round;

    if (val < 0)
        unit = unit + ' -', val = -val;

    arr[0] = Math.floor(val);
    arr[1] = '' + rounder((val * 100) - (arr[0] * 100));

    arr[0] = ('' + arr[0]).replace(re, '$1' + tsep);

    if (arr[1] === '0') 
        arr[1] = ''; // or `usep + '00'`
    else {
        arr[1] = usep + '00'.slice(arr[1].length) + arr[1];
    }

    return unit + arr[0] + arr[1];
}
```

Usage example,

```
currency(220500 / 100); // "£2,205"
currency(-220500 / 100); // "£ -2,205"
```