# How to formatting accounting code

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I would like to display the accounting account code using php from 12345678 to form 123.45.678, is there any one can help me ? Thank you

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to format numbers using javascript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5731193/how-to-format-numbers-using-javascript)

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/149055/how-can-i-format-numbers-as-money-in-javascript (How can I format numbers as money in JavaScript?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use a regex for this with `preg_replace` (for a 8 character digit as in your example) in your php code

```
$number = 12345678;

echo "Number is: ${number}";
$new_number=preg_replace('/(\d{3})(\d{2})(\d{3})/','$1.$2.$3', $number);

echo "Number is: ${new_number}";
```

Answer (score 0):

I wrote this up quickly and it seems to provide the functionality you wanted:

https://jsfiddle.net/tdaeunem/

```
function splitNumber(inputNumber){

    var firstPart = /^(\d{3})/;
    var secondPart = /^\d{3}(\d{2})/;
    var thirdPart = /^\d{5}(\d{3})/;

    var matches = [];

    matches[0] = inputNumber.match(firstPart)[1];

    matches[1] = inputNumber.match(secondPart)[1];

    matches[2] = inputNumber.match(thirdPart)[1];

    return matches.join(".");

}

console.log(splitNumber("12345678"));
```