# Add dollar sign in to currency format?

Tags: javascript, html, numbers, currency

This is the code I have, it returns numbers in currency format but I wish to add the dollar sign ($) before the numbers.

```
document.getElementById("numbers").onblur = function (){    
                this.value = parseFloat(this.value.replace(/,/g, ""))
                    .toFixed(2)
                    .toString()
                    .replace(/\B(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, ",");
                }
```

The id numbers refers to a input text

Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried just using string concatenation? `this.value = "$" + parseFloat(... the rest)`

Comment: @hotforfeature. best possible answer. sometimes people just can't see the forest for the trees...

Comment: @hotforfeature That works but when you try to change the amount again it returns $NaN (Thankyou)

Comment: Based on the comments above you can try remove the dollar sign from the string before doing some calculations and when you are done just add it back.

Comment: `toFixed()` returns a String, you can safely remove the subsequent call to `toString()`. Incidentally I'd suggest displaying the currency using either CSS generated content, or simply inserting an element prior to the element holding the `<input>`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use string concatentation and update your regex to replace both commas and dollar signs with an empty string. That will prevent the `NaN` error when you re-parse the value on another blur change.

```
document.getElementById("numbers").onblur = function (){    
  this.value = "$" + parseFloat(this.value.replace(/(,|\$)/g, "")) // Matches "," or "$" literally
    .toFixed(2)
    .toString()
    .replace(/\B(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, ",");
}
```

Comment: Alternative stick it in a character class: `.replace(/[,$]/g, '')` that will treat `$` literally.

Answer (score 0):

Checkout my answer for a previous question similar to this:

[Adding Two Decimal Places using JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37694286/adding-two-decimal-places-using-javascript/37694423#37694423)

Answer (score 0):

accounting.js is a tiny JavaScript library for number, money and currency formatting.

http://openexchangerates.github.io/accounting.js/

Answer (score 0):

Created codepen url for reference.. I just tried add that onblur function on the input field

```
var x = (document.getElementById("numbers").value);
x = "$"+((x)*1).toFixed(2).replace(/\B(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, ",");
```

http://codepen.io/nagasai/pen/LZGWjp