# JavaScript - Regular Expression to Search for ".x" (where x is any digit that follows a dot)

Tags: javascript

What is the JS regular expression when the pattern must match the first occurrence of ".x", where x can be any digit and . means the decimal point.?

E.g., salary = "5200.2" (it is first defined as a number but then after a few modifications in the lines that follow, it becomes a string before entering the if statement, which is when I am using regular expressions to look for the occurrence of ".x"

```
var salary =5200.2;

salary = salary.toFixed(2); //string
salary = parseFloat(salary);
salary = salary.toLocaleString();
if (!salary.includes('.')){
    salary = salary + ".00"
}else if (salary.includes("/[.[0-9]]/") && salary.charAt(salary.length) == ""){
    salary = salary + '0';
}
```

I need help with the salary.includes("/[.[0-9]]/") && part. Regular expression pattern must be ".0"

What my code sample is trying to accomplish is, if my number is 5200.0 or 5200 it will make it 5,200.00 for both.

Comment: If you plan on displaying this as money, use `num.toLocaleString("en-US", { style: "currency", currency: "USD" })`. It formats everything for you.

Comment: See also [Regex comma seperating thousands and keeping two decimals](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43340193/regex-comma-seperating-thousands-and-keeping-two-decimals/).

Comment: Don't manipulate numbers using regexp.

Comment: @torazaburo What is reason for not manipulating numbers using `RegExp`?

Comment: @guest271314 Because regexp deals with strings, and numbers are not strings. The language provides much better number formatting capabilities than anything you could hack together yourself.

Comment: @torazaburo Do you mean to convey that you have not used `\d` in any `RegExp` relating to strings in any of your answers? Either approach should return same approach when implemented appropriately.

Comment: @guest271314 I have used `\d` when needing to match digits in the course of string manipulation, not to format numbers.

Answer (score 1):

Do not use regexp to do number manipulation and formatting.

It's hard to tell exactly what you want to do, but I can infer that you want to format a number in a locale-specific way, to exactly two decimal places. The correct way to do that is:

```js
const formatter = Intl.NumberFormat("de-DE", {
   minimumFractionDigits: 2,
   maximumFractionDigits: 2
});

const formattedNumber = formatter.format(5200.5);

console.log(formattedNumber);
```

Comment: If this is Answer how is Question not duplicate of [Regex comma seperating thousands and keeping two decimals](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43340193/regex-comma-seperating-thousands-and-keeping-two-decimals/)? Your Answer also ignores the fact that OP is attempting to pass a `RegExp` to `String.prototype.includes()`, which appears to have spawned the Question itself, as that is an issue at `javascript` at Question.

Comment: @guest271314 This falls into the category of a question asking how to use a pair of pliers to pound in a nail. The underlying question is how to format a number. The use of regexp is simply the OP's (ill-advised) approach to that question.

Comment: _"This falls into the category of a question asking how to use a pair of pliers to pound in a nail."_ Not hardly. `RegExp` is suitable to meet requirement, so too are `Array`, `String` or `Intl` methods.

Comment: @guest271314 We'll have to agree to disagree. To format numbers, you should use, uhhh, number formatting utilities. Meanwhile, have fun writing and maintaining your own number formatters using regexp.

Answer (score 0):

`String.prototype.includes()` does not expect regular expression for parameter.

You can use `RegExp.prototype.test()` or `String.prototype.match()` with `RegExp` `/\.\d/` to match first occurrence of `"."` followed by digit character.

Answer (score -1):

You should use `.match` instead of `.includes` (which doesn't accept regex patterns) and tweak your regex to look for a dot followed by a digit:

```
salary.match(/(\.[0-9]+)/)
```

For example:

```js
function formatSalary(salary) {
  salary = salary.toFixed(2); //string
  salary = parseFloat(salary);
  salary = salary.toLocaleString();
  if (!salary.includes('.')){
      salary = salary + ".00"
  } else if (salary.match(/(\.[\d]{1})$/)) {
      salary = salary + '0';
  }
  return salary;
}

console.log(formatSalary(5200))
console.log(formatSalary(5200.0))
console.log(formatSalary(5200.2))
console.log(formatSalary(5200.21))
```

Comment: if the input salary is 5200.21 it makes it 5200.210 ..? Also, can you explain what each character in the regular expression /(\.[0-9]+)/ does, or can you link me to a regular expressions article page for javascript? I can't find a detailed link on w3schools.