# Format number with point as a separaror in javascript

Tags: javascript, regex

How to make a format number like below in javascript, i try workit with some regex, but it's not working.

> 99.999.999.9.999.999

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to format numbers using javascript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5731193/how-to-format-numbers-using-javascript)

Comment: *99.999.999.9.999.999* after which logic?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a regular expression with positive lookahead for a special length to the end of the string.

```js
var regex = /(?=(.{13}|.{10}|.{7}|.{6}|.{3})$)/g,
    value = '999999999999999',
    result = value.replace(regex, '.');
    
console.log(result);
```

Comment: Perfect! Thanks Nina !

Answer (score 1):

```
(9999999999999).toString().split("").reverse().map((el,i)=>(i+1)%3==0?"."+el:el).reverse().join("");
```

Make a string array out of it, then start from behind and add a point after each third element, then create a String out of that.

http://jsbin.com/lepecoyedo/edit?console

Alternatively, with fixed , positions:

```
var num=(9999999999999).toString().split("").reverse();
[3,6,7].forEach((i,o)=>num.splice(o+i,0,"."));//positions 3,6,8 (or others) from behind
num=num.reverse().join("");
```

http://jsbin.com/xahopuhira/edit?console

Comment: Hi Jonas, thanks for your help but the format should be exactly 99.999.999.9.999.999 , and you code result is 9.999.999.999.999, i have no idea how to split the number