# Display number in specific format

Tags: javascript, format, int, currency

If an Int is bigger than 1000, how would you go about displaying it as a currency?

1500 as an example, needs to be 1.500,00

So anything above 1000 needs to have a dot and a comma followed by 2 zero's, what's a proper way to do this?

Comment: With a `number_format` function. Googling `format number php` will tell you the same.

Comment: Take a look at the [NumberFormatter](http://php.net/manual/en/class.numberformatter.php) class as well

Comment: Sorry, I meant Javascript, changed it.

Comment: duplicate https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5731193/how-to-format-numbers-using-javascript

Comment: Also, Stack Overflow is not a code request site. Please add your code.

Comment: Well then use `Number.prototype.toLocaleString()` which is the first result from googling `format number javascript`. Please read [how to ask a question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) because you've done 0 research.

Answer (score 2):

That's easy with the built-in php function `number_format`:

The first argument is the number, the second is how many decimals you'd like to have, then the seperator between the decimals and the number and then the thousand seperator.

Example:

```
$formattedNumber = number_format(1234, 2, ',', '.'); // => 1.234,00
```

More information: https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.number-format.php

Comment: Sorry, I meant Javascript.

Comment: Please move the important part of the link to the answer body itself so when the link dies, visitors can still view the information.

Comment: Okay, do you expect something like giving more examples @SteveFest?

Comment: @jens1o You already gave an good example. Please copy the main points of the page you provided to your post so that we can view it easier.

Comment: @SteveFest like this?