# Modify countup jquery functions to include commas?

Tags: jquery

How would I modify the following to include commas in the output? For example output of `300000` would print as `300,000'?

the html

```
<span class="number counter" data-count="300000">300,000</span>
```

the magic:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    $('.counter').each(function() {
        var $this = $(this),
            countTo = $this.attr('data-count');


        $({countNum: $this.text()}).animate({
                countNum: countTo
            },
            {
                duration: 999,
                easing:'linear',
                step: function() {
                    $this.text(Math.floor(this.countNum));
                },
                complete: function() {
                    $this.text(addCommas(this.countNum));
                    console.log('finished')
                }
            });

        function addCommas(nStr){
            //return comma
        }
    });
});
```

This is different from - [How do I format numbers using JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5731193/how-do-i-format-numbers-using-javascript) - because I need to countup and display counter with comma - the action during `step` is what requires dynamic comma being added.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I format numbers using JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5731193/how-do-i-format-numbers-using-javascript)

Comment: the question's most popular answer is using a library, which isn't the best solution. secondly, you will find the problem at hand is including commas "during countup" and not when the countup function is completed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use regex:

```
nStr.toString().replace(/(\d)(?=(\d\d\d)+(?!\d))/g, "$1,");
```

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    $('.counter').each(function() {
        var $this = $(this),
            countTo = $this.attr('data-count');


        $({countNum: $this.text()}).animate({
                countNum: countTo
            },
            {
                duration: 999,
                easing:'linear',
                step: function() {
                    $this.text(addCommas(Math.floor(this.countNum)));
                },
                complete: function() {
                    $this.text(addCommas(this.countNum));
                    console.log('finished')
                }
            });

        function addCommas(nStr){
            return nStr.toString().replace(/(\d)(?=(\d\d\d)+(?!\d))/g, "$1,");
        }
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span class="number counter" data-count="300000">300,000</span>
```

Comment: that would not work as it does not include the comma during countup - only shows comma after it is printed to screen.

Comment: Then use `addCommas()` in `animate.step` instead of `animate.complete`.

Comment: no that would not work. it results in `NaN` during the step counting

Comment: Edited the answer so you can see the changes in `animate.step`.

Comment: very helpful! you rock thank you so much for your help with this.

Comment: Glad it could help! :)