# How to perform comma and decimal separation of a number using javascript?

Tags: javascript

I have a value 2000000 and i want this to be formatted as 2,000,000.00

below is the script i have tried but not able to get the exact output.

```
function myFunction() {
  var num = 2000000;

  var c = num.toLocaleString()
  var n = num.toString().replace(/\B(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, ",");
  //var number=n.
  var number = parseInt(n).toFixed(2);
  document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = n;
  document.getElementById("demmo").innerHTML = number;
}
```

This function gives 2,000,000 and 2.00 but it should be 2,000,000.00
help me to get the required result.

Comment: Possible duplicate of: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5731193/how-do-i-format-numbers-using-javascript

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
function myFunction() {
  var num = 2000000.00;

   var c = num.toLocaleString();
   var substr = c.split('.');
   var decimal = substr[1];
   var intVal= substr[0];

   var n = intVal.toString().replace(/\B(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, ",");
   //var number=n.
   var number = n+ decimal;
   document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = n;
   document.getElementById("demmo").innerHTML = number;
}
```

Comment: You converted the value to string and added **,**. Thats how it has to be done. Then after you are converting the string to number which only gets 2 as the number which ignores the rest after **,** . You need to add .00 during the string replace. It's like concatenating. `n=n+".00"`

Comment: i got your point but if the value is 2000000.87 then appending .00 will not work right?

Comment: Yeah.In that case you have to separate the decimal and integer at the very beginning. Then do your process adding **,** and then concatenate the decimal which you have already separated to a variable.

Comment: Updated my answer.Please check it out

Comment: thanks. its working after handling the undefined case.

Comment: Happy to here that friend

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/176797/discussion-between-t-arunkumar-and-ramesh).

Answer (score 4):

Use `toFixed`, then add the , and ensure that there are two 0 at the end:

```
const addTo = (add, length) => str => str.length >= length ? str : addTo(add, length)(str + add);
const chunk = (sym, length) => str => str.length < length ? str : chunk(sym, length)(str.substr(0, str.length - length)) + sym + str.substr(str.length - length);


const [num, fraction] = 2000000..toFixed(2).split(".");
return chunk(",", 3)(num) + "." + addTo("0", 2)(fraction);
```

Answer (score 4):

You could use the [NumberFormat](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/NumberFormat) object of the ECMAScript Internationalization API:

```js
let num = 2000000;
let l10nEN = new Intl.NumberFormat("en-US", { minimumFractionDigits: 2 });

console.log(l10nEN.format(num));
```

Or simply use the [toLocaleString()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toLocaleString) method of the number type:

```js
let num = 2000000;

console.log(num.toLocaleString("en-US", { minimumFractionDigits: 2 }));
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
    num.toLocaleString('en', { minimumFractionDigits:2 })
```

Comment: it gives 2000000.00 but the required format is 2,000,000.00

Answer (score 2):

You could use [`Number.prototype.toLocaleString()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toLocaleString) and [`Number.prototype.toFixed()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toFixed) to achieve the required result.

**DEMO**

```js
let value = 2000000;

value = value.toFixed(2).split('.');

console.log(Number(value[0]).toLocaleString('en') + '.' + value[1]);

value= 2000000.87;

value = value.toFixed(2).split('.');

console.log(Number(value[0]).toLocaleString('en') + '.' + value[1]);
```