# Change number in div to theree digit comma

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I have a price div in my website like this:

```
<div id="price"> 20000 </div>
```

Now I'm looking for a JavaScript method to add commas every three digits in all of my price "div"s.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to format numbers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5731193/how-to-format-numbers)

Comment: @David Unfortunately this in this topic they give number inline of js code, but i want add digits to my html div prices and i'm newbie in js and can't change that topic code

Comment: `parseInt(document.getElementById("price").innerHTML)` will give you the content of your div as a number.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [`toLocaleString`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toLocaleString).

```js
const priceDiv = document.querySelector('#price');
priceDiv.textContent = (+priceDiv.textContent).toLocaleString('en-US');
```

```html
<div id="price">20000</div>
```

Comment: The code is OK , but not works in my template even when i remove my other JS files
Do you have any advices?

Comment: @SeyyedMohammadHosseini What do you mean by that? Could you provide a [mcve]?

Comment: ` <script type="text/javascript">
const priceDiv = document.querySelector('#pprices');
priceDiv.textContent = (+priceDiv.textContent).toLocaleString('en-US');
</script>
<div id="pprices">211212</div>`

Comment: @SeyyedMohammadHosseini You need to put the `script` tag after all of the elements, before the closing body tag.